# Samsung 305u notebook won't resume after suspension

Tags: 12.04, drivers, suspend, lid

I'm having trouble with my samsung 305u notebook suspending, both when inactive or when I close the lid. I read it is a video driver problem, so I uninstalled the proprietary driver from system settings-> additional drivers and the problem was solved. Since I need to have video drivers installed, I got the Catalyst Suit drivers from AMD. I think I got them installed correctly since when I put `fglrxinfo` in the terminal the result is:

```
display: :0.0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 6320 Graphics
OpenGL version string: 4.2.11762 Compatibility Profile Context
```

The problem is that when I install the Catalyst Suite the suspension problem comes  back again. The only difference I could perceive is that when the drivers are uninstalled and the notebook goes to suspension it doesn't completely turn off, and when the drivers are installed the notebook turns off and I have to press the ON botton, after I do this it sound like it's on but the screen remains black.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must install Catalyst drivers from AMD.

Follow this guide:

> [What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers)

I have installed Catalyst 12.10 Drivers and finally, after 6 month about non return from sleep when suspend, now my Samsung 305u can wake up. Good luck.

Comment: I read you're comment and updated my Ubuntu to 12.10, is it normal that my notebook now wakes up without me installing the ATI Catalyst Video Drivers? With the opensource one pre-installed seems to work fine.

Thanks for your answear!